# Properly Format DateTime on XML Datetime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to serialize an entity using XML serialization on SQL. Unfortunately I notice that my datetime is not properly read. I am returning a 24 hour format, but on SQL, its reading a different time. Here is the exact SQL Stored Procedure:

```
DECLARE
@XML XML = '- <ArrayEntityView>
                - <entEntity>
                        <dtModifiedDate>2017-07-24T14:09:20.4483795+08:00</dtModifiedDate> 
                  </entEntity>
                </ArrayEntityView>'

        DECLARE @tblProcAssign TABLE 
          ( 

             dtmoddate    DATETIME
          ) 

        INSERT INTO @tblProcAssign 
                    (
                    dtmoddate
                     ) 
        SELECT entuserunits.value('dtModifiedDate[1]', 'DATETIME') AS dtModDate 
        FROM   @XML.nodes('ArrayEntityView/entEntity')entUserUnits(entuserunits) 


        select * from @tblProcAssign
```

Based on the code above, I am passing a date:

```
2017-07-24T14:09:20.4483795+08:00
```

But on SQL, its reading is:

```
2017-07-24 06:09:20.447
```

And I am not sure why, it should be:

```
2017-07-24 14:09:20.447
```

The data came from c# code DateTime.Now. I don't want to use GetDate in SQL since sometimes, I am not using DateTime.Now. How should I format this entity or any parsing I need to do so that I will get my expected result?

Comment: See this link for more information about datetime offsets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch the data type from `datetime` to `datetimeoffset` if you want time zone information to be recognised. Without it, only the actual time value (that is, UTC) is returned.

Make sure that the data type is replaced in both the table definition and the XML `value()` method:

```
DECLARE @tblProcAssign TABLE (dtmoddate datetimeoffset);

INSERT INTO @tblProcAssign (dtmoddate) 
SELECT entuserunits.value('dtModifiedDate[1]', 'datetimeoffset') AS dtModDate 
FROM @XML.nodes('ArrayEntityView/entEntity')entUserUnits(entuserunits);
```